# What is the partial of the Ridge Regression Cost Function?

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

What is the partial of the Ridge Regression Function? Does it provide insight to a gradient descent with ridge Regression? I am using Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow Geron.

$$\mathbf{Ridge \ Regression\ Equation} => J(\hat\theta) = MSE(\hat\theta) + \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i^2 $$
$$\mathbf{ Gradient\ Descent\ Equation} => \frac{\delta}{\delta\theta_j}MSE=\frac{2}m\sum_{i=1}^m(\hat\theta^Tx^{(i)}-y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your ridge term is: $R = \alpha\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i^2$

Its partial derivative can be computed using the [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) and the [linearity of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Differentiation_is_linear):

$$
\frac{\delta}{\delta \theta_j}R = 2\alpha\theta_j
$$

You also asked for some insight, so here it is: In the context of gradient descent, this means that there's a force pushing each weight $\theta_j$ to get smaller. If a given weight doesn't have much effect on the loss function, then it will tend to get pushed towards a very small value. This can help to prevent overfitting, where weights with weak effects on the loss are pushed to unrealistically large values, just because it decreases the loss a little bit.